# How to add remove button for items in widget : entityreference view widget?

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I installed entityreference_view_widget and i have created a view for entity reference then i created a field entityreference view

but i want now customize my widget entityreference view, i want add a remove button for every items added 
[image]

how i can add a "remove" button for every items inn the widget of rentity reference view field ?
there was a module who do that or a php code? help me plz

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this on a project using some jQuery.

Unchecking a checkbox for a row than saving the node removes the row, so:

- hide the checkbox via CSS
- using jQuery.each() add a remove button, link, whatever to each row
- on button click just uncheck the checkbox for that row and than .hide() the row